# PHP 7 Bool Type Hint Not Working

Tags: php, oop, type-hinting

Im a bit stumped with a scalar Type Hint issue (which PHP7 should be able to handle). Basically, Im creating a method with the `bool` type hint to only allow booleans to be passed. However it fails and lets other types like strings passed. I believe in the past this worked for me. Take a look at the snippet as an example. The first dump results in `false` (which makes sense since `'test'` is a string), the second dump results in `true` which does not make sense to me. I was hoping for a PHP error to trigger since the type is not a boolean. Any thoughts?

```
<?php
class Test{
    function something(bool $test){
       var_dump($test); // "Second dump"
    }
}

$value = 'test';
var_dump(is_bool($value)); // "First dump"
$test = new Test;
$test->something($value);
```

Results:

```
bool(false) 
bool(true)
```

Comment: In PHP 5.6 this produced an error: https://3v4l.org/Uo7j0

Comment: Have you enabled strict typing?

Comment: @JulienLachal I have not. Not sure where to enable it. Ill Google that. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must declare *strict typing* [1] in the file in order to force PHP to not do *type coercion* [2].

[1] -- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict

[2] -- "By default, PHP will coerce values of the wrong type into the expected scalar type if possible."

`php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);`

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for. Thanks. Still running tests.

Comment: Note this doesnt work for anything called via reflection unfortunatly. Im using a reflection method and passing along params from another class and strict types has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that PHP has automatic conversion for primitives. They did not change this for a long time probably for philosophic reasons. This why previously primitive type hinting was forbidden in PHP: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29508

As PHP has automatic conversions you should do this in order to be sure:

```
class Test{
    function something($test){
       if(!is_bool($test)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Boolean expected.");
       }
    }
}
```

Edit: Read the following article on scalar type hinting in PHP 7 https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/269-PHP-7-Scalar-Type-Hinting-Finally-Approved.html

In PHP 7 it finally is possible to make a code containing primitive type checking work by adding

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

in the beginning of the file.

Comment: make it an InvalidArgumentException

Answer (score 1):

The magic feature you are looking for is this one. Put it on the first line above your class!

```
declare(strict_types=1) ;
```

Now your code will look klike this:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1) ;

class Test{
    function something(bool $test){
       var_dump($test); // "Second dump"
    }
}

$value = 'test';
var_dump(is_bool($value)); // "First dump"
$test = new Test;
$test->something($value);
```

Now it will throw an error! http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict

See it working here: https://3v4l.org/eLS1T

One last point, you need to set this on a **per file basis**